# Spring form error does not display: Controller, command or template issue?

Tags: validation, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I am trying to create a Spring MVC webapp, and I want to add some Validation to my forms, with Thymeleaf.
The app is running but the Validation doesn't seem to work, as nothing is displayed.

Here is my Command class:

```
public class WatchlistItem {

private Integer id;

@NotBlank(message="Please, enter all the fields")
private String title;

private String rating;

private String priority;

@Size(max=50, message="Comment should be maximum 50 characters")
private String comment;
```

My Controller:

```
@Controller
public class WatchlistController {

private final List<WatchlistItem> watchlistItems = new ArrayList<>();
private static int index = 1;

@PostMapping("/watchlistItemForm")
public ModelAndView submitWatchlistItemForm(@Valid WatchlistItem watchlistItem, BindingResult bindingResult) {

    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        return new ModelAndView("watchlistItemForm");
    }

    WatchlistItem existingItem = findWatchlistItemById(watchlistItem.getId());

    if (existingItem == null) {
        watchlistItem.setId(index++);
        watchlistItems.add(watchlistItem);
    } else {
        existingItem.setComment(watchlistItem.getComment());
        existingItem.setPriority(watchlistItem.getPriority());
        existingItem.setRating(watchlistItem.getRating());
        existingItem.setTitle(watchlistItem.getTitle());
    }

    RedirectView redirect = new RedirectView();
    redirect.setUrl("/watchlist");

    return new ModelAndView(redirect);
}
```

And finally the template of my .html:

```
   <form action="#" method="post" th:action="@{/watchlistItemForm}" th:object="${watchlistItem}">
  <h2 class = "mt-4">Submit an item</h2>
  <hr/>
  <div class = "form-group row ">
     <label for = "title" class = "col-sm-2 col-form-label">Title</label>
     <div class = "col-sm-4">
        <input th:field="*{title}" type = "text" class = "form-control" placeholder = "Mandatory">
     </div>
     <div class="col-sm-4">
        <span class="text-danger" th:errors="*{title}"> </span>
     </div>
  </div>
```

I already had a look on the following post: [Spring Error form not displayed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26013906/spring-error-form-not-displayed), but nothing worked.
The issue is that I have no idea where the problem comes from, the controller, the command or the html page.

Comment: The problem is your controller code. You are destroying the model. Use `return new ModelAndVIew("watchListItemForm", bindingResult.getModel());"` or just return a `String` instead of a `ModelAndView`.

Comment: I just tried, unfortunately it doesn't change anything.

Comment: Did you include a validation implementation like `hibernate-validator` or just the api?

Comment: No, only the api for now

Comment: Without an implementation, validation won't work because there is nothing that does the validation.